# 'ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional.' How do I rectify this error?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I have attached my code below, it is a  model of the two body problem.I have tried to use 1D vectors as my argument for the odeint function but I still face the error. Suggestions are much appreciated.

```
tspan = np.linspace(0,p,(p/60.0)+1.0)
x0 = np.empty((6,1))
x0[0]=r[0]
x0[1]=r[1]
x0[2]=r[2]
x0[3]=v[0]
x0[4]=v[1]
x0[5]=v[2]
tspan = np.linspace(0,p,(p/60.0)+1.0)
x = odeint(ot.odetwobody,x0,tspan)
def odetwobody(x,t):
    mu = 398600.0
    r = np.sqrt(x[1]**2+x[2]**2+x[3]**2)
    xddot = np.empty((6,1))
    xddot[0] = x[3]
    xddot[1]=x[4]
    xddot[2]=x[5]
    xddot[3]=(-mu*x[0])/r**3
    xddot[4]=(-mu*x[1])/r**3
    xddot[5]=(-mu*x[2])/r**3
    return xddot
```

Comment: It usually helps if you specify where (what line) you get the error.

Comment: The error appears when the program call odeint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial condition is `x0`. You just need to change it from the forced 2D-but-not-really `x0 = np.empty((6,1))` to the fully 1d `x0 = np.empty(6)`.

Comment: Worked,Perfect!. Thank you for the immediate response!!

Comment: Not a problem! Please accept the answer given that this one is solved :)